# Is System.Text.Json.JsonSerializerOptions thread-safe?

Tags: .net-core, .net-7.0

I am writing an asp.net core web application.

I have a number of classes that share the same [Json serialization options](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.text.json.jsonserializeroptions?view=net-7.0). I would like to factor in these options in a single location

My approach is to create a static class that provide all these options for different aspects of teh application.

I would like to know if I can create a static member for the options or if I need to create a new instance each time is is required, **keeping in mind that several concurrent threads will be using the instance returned**.

In other words, can I write:

```
public static class JsonOptionsProviders
{
    public static readonly JsonSerializerOptions ForPreferences = new() { Converters = { new DateOnlyJsonConverter(), new TimeOnlyJsonConverter() } };
}
```

or do I have to write:

```
public static class JsonOptionsProviders
{
    public static JsonSerializerOptions ForPreferences => new() { Converters = { new DateOnlyJsonConverter(), new TimeOnlyJsonConverter() } };
}
```

Comment: No it's built from regular types so if you plan on changing them during runtime - it won't be "thread safe".
However since It's a simple object you should create a ``const`` json serializer and then it would be thread safe since it's not mutating during runtime.
It has a copy ctor, so if you need to alter the configuration, copy it and alter the new instance.

Comment: `JsonSerializerOptions` isn't a simple object, it caches serialization metadata. The docs explain it's thread-safe and meant to be reused

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`JsonSerializerOptions` isn't a simple data class but it's designed to be reused. From the [Reuse JsonSerializerOptions instances](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/serialization/system-text-json/configure-options?pivots=dotnet-7-0#reuse-jsonserializeroptions-instances) section of [How to instantiate JsonSerializerOptions instances with System.Text.Json](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/serialization/system-text-json/configure-options?pivots=dotnet-7-0#reuse-jsonserializeroptions-instances)

> If you use JsonSerializerOptions repeatedly with the same options, don't create a new JsonSerializerOptions instance each time you use it. Reuse the same instance for every call. This guidance applies to code you write for custom converters and when you call JsonSerializer.Serialize or JsonSerializer.Deserialize. It's safe to use the same instance across multiple threads. The metadata caches on the options instance are thread-safe, and the instance is immutable after the first serialization or deserialization.

The performance difference in the article's example is 190ms for a reused instance vs 40140 for a new instance every time.

The `JsonSerializerOptions` class is used to cache metadata for the serialized types.

> The serializer undergoes a warm-up phase during the first serialization of each type in the object graph when a new options instance is passed to it. This warm-up includes creating a cache of metadata that is needed for serialization. The metadata includes delegates to property getters, setters, constructor arguments, specified attributes, and so forth. This metadata cache is stored in the options instance. The same warm-up process and cache applies to deserialization.